# Azure storage Info

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am new to azure API, what kind of data or log following azure storage account has
Blogs:
        Events ?
        wad-control-container
        wad-iis-logfiles
        any more ?
Tables
        Events
        WADDirectoriesTable
        WADLogsTable
        WADPerformanceCountersTable
        WADWindowsEventLogsTable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows Azure Hosted Service can logs 7 types(4 in Table Storage and 3 in Blob Storage) of logs in Azure Storage, which are as follows:

1. Event Logs: logs in WADWindowsEventLogsTable
2. Performance Counter: logs in WADPerformanceCountersTable
3. Trace Logs: logs in WADLogsTable
4. Infrastruture Logs: logs in WADDiagnosticsInfrastructureLogsTable

Remaining 3 types of logs are stored in Blob Storage

1. IIS Logs: logs in wad-iis-logfiles Blob container
2. Failed Request Logs: logs in wad-iis-failedreqlogfiles Blob container
3. Crash Dumps: logs in wad-crash-dumps blob container

Hope this helps.

Thanks.